# here api shows smaller trafficTime for route with same start and end points but via addtional waypoint

Tags: here-api

How come trafficTime (fastest) from A to B is longer than trafficTime from A to B via C, in the same arrival/departure times?

V7 requests:
A to B: trafficTime = 4979 seconds
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=KEY&waypoint0=32.6289624435649%2C35.079885159610136&waypoint1=32.0155%2C34.7505&mode=fastest%3Bcar&combineChange=true&language=he&instructionformat=text&departure=2020-05-21T10:00:00.000Z

A to B via C: trafficTime = 4936 seconds
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=KEY&waypoint0=32.6289624435649%2C35.079885159610136&waypoint1=32.119485%2C34.938341&waypoint2=32.0155%2C34.7505&mode=fastest%3Bcar&combineChange=true&language=he&instructionformat=text&departure=2020-05-21T10:00:00.000Z

V8 also
A to B: duration = 3987 seconds
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&return=travelSummary,summary,polyline,actions&origin=32.6289624435649,35.079885159610136&destination=32.0155,34.7505&apikey=KEY

A to B via C: duration = 3955 seconds
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&return=travelSummary,summary,polyline,actions&origin=32.6289624435649,35.079885159610136&destination=32.0155,34.7505&via=32.119485,34.938341!stopDuration=0&apikey=KEY

If I request to show several alternatives (available only without "arrival" param) I get even faster and shorter route:
V7 A to B with alternatives: fastest trafficTime = 4765
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=KEY&waypoint0=32.6289624435649%2C35.079885159610136&waypoint1=32.0155%2C34.7505&mode=fastest%3Bcar&combineChange=true&language=he&instructionformat=text&departure=2020-05-21T10:00:00.000Z&alternatives=9

Answer (score 0):

creating the same scenario at our end, clearly shows that their is significant route change when we have specified the intermediate waypoint as given in API which is reducing the travel time. please chk the attachment

[image]

Comment: Hey, it proves that the initial route wasn't the fastest.
Moreover, by quering alternatives I can find a faster route.